# Failed to install [Name] MsiExec returned: 255, when running an cmd file from Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

I'm trying to run an MSI install command from Powershell by using a cmd file.
I create my install command:

```
msiexec /i [insert here a HUGE amount of param values] /lv install.log /passive
```

I then write it to **temp.cmd** and then execute from Powershell as follows:

```
$exitCode = (Start-Process -FilePath "temp.cmd" -Wait -Passthru).ExitCode
```

I then get the following error message:

> CategoryInfo : OperationStopped: 255:String
> RuntimeException 
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId
>   Failed to install [Msi Name] MsiExec returned: 255

What causes this?

Comment: It's not possible to answer the question from an msiexec perpsective if you don't show the contents of temp.cmd

Comment: thanks!, the actual command is too long to post, so I added a short version to give context to what I am doing.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you'd have a really long command.  If you are setting a ton of public properties you should consider using a transform  (foo.mst TRANSFORMS=foo.mst)  to encapsulate that and shorten your command line.

Comment: Its a design issue with a legacy Powershell script, it grabs ALL the variables from a config file and sends them to each installer. I added this question to SO, in case anyone Google's the error and now they hopefully will find some help. Thanks for the TRANSFORMS heads up, didn't know about this, so I'll spike that and see how I go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try and run the MsiExec command I was having trouble with from the commandline, I get the following error message:

> The input line is too long

This error isn't obvious when executed in Powershell and you might think its an issue with MsiExec.

This is a bit of a cryptic error message and relates to cmd.exe having a total commandline length of 8191.
See the Microsoft KB article on cmd length: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473